# Restore a databricks job which has been deleted

Tags: logging, databricks, workflow, jobs

I find that a job (workflow) were deleted in databricks.

Is there a way to restore a deleted job ?
And to know the userID who has done the deletion?

I tried to see if databricks CLI can be used to see a kind of history related to jobs. But I didn't find something.